# Steiner's fundamental theorem - Why the $3$-gon is also equilateral?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Related to the proposition $6$ (page $820$) of the article [Sound of Symmetry](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rowlett/monthly.pdf), could anyone be able to tell me why the $3$-gon $P$ is equilateral (they use the Steiner's fundamental theorem (page $819$).) I think this is a trivial question, but I am stuck to answer it.

> **Steiner's fundamental theorem :** Among all triangles with the same base and height, the isosceles has the smallest perimeter.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Could you explain you point? I would appreciate if you could do that. I work on that problem since a while, but I don't unblock.

Comment: Let the base side be, say, $BC$, and the foot point of the altitude be $X$. Suppose $|BC|=a$(fixed), $|BX|=x$, height$=h$. Then perimeter$=a+\sqrt{x^2+h^2}+\sqrt{(a-x)^2+h^2}$. Apply the triangle inequality or do some calculus to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $P$ is a triangle that maximizes the ratio of area to perimeter squared.  This means that if $Q$ is any other triangle with the same area as $P$, the perimeter of $Q$ is greater than or equal to the perimeter of $P$.

Now suppose $P$ is not equilateral.  Choose one side of $P$ as a base such that the other two sides do not have equal length.  Let $Q$ be the isosceles triangle with that same base and the same height as $P$.  Then $Q$ has the same area as $P$, so it must have greater or equal perimeter.  But $P$ is not isosceles with respect to this base, so by Steiner's theorem $Q$ has smaller perimeter than $P$.*  This is a contradiction.

*As stated, Steiner's theorem may be interpreted to say the perimeter of $Q$ is less than or equal to the perimeter of $P$.  But if you look at the proof on page 819, it actually gives a strict inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let the base be $BC$. Consider a line parallel to the base at a distance equal to the height. We need to find the point $A$ on this line such that $AB+AC$ is minimum. If we consider a light source at $B$, the ray of light from $B$ that passes through $C$ travels the smallest distance. Hence by the principle of reflection, angle of incidence must be equal to the angle of reflection at $A$ and it immediately follows that $AB = AC$.